# wp_query exclude word and category

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to exclude word 'Vape' and exclude category using wp_query. Is it possible?

```
$args = array(

's' => '-Vape',
'cat' => '-62',
'posts_per_page'=>'16',
'paged'=>$paged,
'orderby' => 'date',
'order'   => 'DESC'
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

I use the code above but its not working. I don't get the items that have in their title the word 'Vape' which is right but i get the items of the category 62...any help appreciated!